# Gauss Law for infinite objects - Components

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

For an infinite rod, the formula would be $E=2k\lambda/R$ using a cylinder. If we have a point in space and wanted to only calculate the $z$-component, I assume we would do $E_z=\cos\theta$.  How would the theta work out because wouldn't $\theta$ be anything from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: To calculate the z component you just do $\vec{E}\cdot \hat{k}$, (or $\hat{z}$ if you use that notation).